# Android Unresolved reference: findNavController error

Tags: android, kotlin, navigationcontroller, android-jetpack

**I am using Kotlin and have all references added in my project.**

```
// Navigation
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:$rootProject.nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$rootProject.nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.nav_version"
```

**I also have these on top of the build.gradle**

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'`

**And I am using it like this inside my fragment**

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment(){

    ...

    override fun onCategoryItemClicked(category: Category) {
        view.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.phrasesFragment)
    }
}
```

**I can see this generated extension(file) too**

```
fun Fragment.findNavController(): NavController =
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
```

Comment: I guess view is not a fragment

Comment: `NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment)` is applicable for a container fragment containing child fragments. If you want to access the `NavController` for a fragment definition in the activity use `View.findNavController()` method

Comment: @TimCastelijns it's a fragment

Comment: @HawkPriest it's inside the fragment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lots of try and error, I found the source of issue. upgrading my gradle to `gradle:3.3.0-alpha06` was the key. I revert it to the previous version and it works fine now.
So I think something is happening there which needs to be fixed by #Google.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha05'
```

By the way while using tha latest version of the gradle(At the time of writing this, I mean `gradle:3.3.0-alpha06`), this will work

```
    Navigation.findNavController(view!!).navigate(R.id.phrasesFragment)
```

instead of

```
override fun onCategoryItemClicked(category: Category) {
    view.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.phrasesFragment)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, this was a very frustrating issue for me as well. New Gradle update borked half of the dependencies i worked with. Made today a wild goose chase! Come on Google! Do BETTER!

Comment: I also noticed this but at first I tough was something else cause I upgraded different things along with the gradle plugin https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112806420

Comment: @DanieleSegato I raised an issue against Gradle but it turned out its google or android studio problem so I don't know where to raise it!

Comment: There are multiple issue about this on the Android issue tracker, just go star them :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, downgrading navigation libraries helped.

I downgraded from `2.3.5` to `2.3.4`.

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4'
```

`2.3.5` was latest stable at the time of writing this answer.

Just try changing version of the library, and see which works. [Find versions here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_234_3).

Answer (score -1):

Just add this in your build.gradle(:app)  -

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Comment: `kotlin-android-extensions` is deprecated best not using it anymore 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).